# Enabling FIPS 140-2 compliance mode in MULE ESB

Tags: java, security, mule, fips

To enable the FIPS 140-2 compliance mode I had gone through MULE documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/fips-140-2-compliance-support.

I had followed the steps mentioned below as per recommended in MULE documentation :

1. Copy cryptojce.jar, cryptojcommon.jar & jcmFIPS.jar in ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ext
2. Edit java.security file (${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/java.security) add security.provider.1=com.rsa.jsafe.provider.JsafeJCE.
3. Edit wrapper.conf file (mule/conf/wrapper.conf) add wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dmule.security.model=fips140-2.
4. Start Mule. On mule console I got the message mentioned below:

---

Mule ESB and Integration Platform
 Version: 3.5.2 Build:....
 MuleSoft, Inc.
 **Security model: fips140-2**

---

From the message it is clear that FIPS140-2 is used as security model. Even after providing three JAR’s out of four of RSA’s BSAFE as certified security provider.

How can I verify that FIPS 140-2 compliance mode is enable on Mule ?

This message is also shown even If I don't prepare the Java Env as mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message, as the docs say, is only linked to running mule in FIPS security mode so that cipher suites are restricted to the approved ones. 
You need to be running Mule in a proper Java environment to have full compliance, which is what the docs are specifying at the beginning, so you need to follow all the steps.
I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But as you said Mule relies on JAVA to have full compliance that means If Java Env is fully compliant then Mule automatically becomes compliant whether or not compliant flag is enabled on Mule end. I think the only thing change is filtered cipher suites & protocols are enabled if the compliant flag is enabled in Mule.

Does Mule perform some kind of internal check that whether JAVA Env is compliant or not when FIPS compliant flag is enabled?

And what changes take place when Mule runs in FIPS compliance mode Apart from using selective cipher suites & protocols?

Comment: "Mule automatically becomes compliant whether or not compliant flag is enabled": no, in that case Mule would be "almost compliant" since a proper security provider will be used but a cipher suite could potentially be selected that's not valid in the 140-2 standard. But yes, the ciphers and protocols are the only thing affected, as you say. There's no check to validate that the env is compliant. As for the changes, Mule only handles the ciphers/protocols, the rest is done by the security provider selected (so I can't be more specific there). HTH

Comment: Thanks! I think the conclusion is JAVA Env + Mule both needs to be required to be FIPS compliant in order to have MULE in fully FIPS compliance mode as Mule doesn't provide any internal checks.